# Allow multiple email addressed per account in firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I have a project with an account model that should allow multiple email addresses per account. According to the Firebase documentation, this can be set in the following panel in the authentication console.

[image]

However even with that correctly set, calling `updateEmail(user, 'some@email.com)` will throw the `auth/email-already-in-use` error if the email has already been used.

How do I prevent the above error?